# Game architecture & methodology (screens/effects)

Tags: java, android, architecture, methodology

I'm looking into how I should design my games in regards to management/transitioning of different "screens" as well as effect timings. I'm currently using AndEngine on Android, which doesn't have an explicit game loop, although I'm interested in hearing how these issues are dealt with both with or without a game loop.

1. I've already written a temporary system that I'm using to handle the different "screens" in my game (splash, menu, game, options etc), which is based on "scenes" within AndEngine. I've got 3 base "scenes" which act as layers for a background, content and popups. Each Screen has onTransitionIn() and onTransitionOut() methods which are called by the ScreenManager when it's own methods (such as closePopup(), that sort of thing) are called. However, all code in the transition methods would obviously be run at once, meaning all animations, the screen status etc would be executed instantly. To overcome this problem, I used the postDelayed(runnable, delay) method in the Android Handler class. That way, I was able to change the screen status after the transition animations were completed and run one animation after another. Now the entire system is pretty much based on running delayed code via the handler. Unsurprisingly, it's crude, not particularly stable and generally amateurish.
2. The second issue regarding "effect timings" is closely linked to my usage of the Handler class. Let's just say I want to create an effect when a user completes a task, where some animation is played and a number is increased on the screen. At the moment, the only way of having one run after the other is by using the Handler. As stated previously, this appears to me like a crude/unstable/amateurish method.

I'd really like to know how these issues are generally handled in games (both with/without an explicit loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like when you want to trigger a chain of actions, you're basically firing them all off at once, each with some fixed delay. This is quite fragile - if you change the duration of one of the actions, it might no longer sync up with something that's supposed to happen after it.

A more robust approach would be to use the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Each action could have an `onCompleted()` event (and/or various other events, depending on the nature of the action), which could be used to trigger the start of the next action.

For example, let's say that when the user presses the selects a menu item, you want this sequence of events:

1. Play an animation of the selected item.
2. When 1 is finished, transition the current screen off.
3. When 2 is finished, transition the next screen on.

It sounds like you're doing something like this:

```
void onItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    runNow(new SelectedItemAnimationHandler(menuItem)); // Takes 500ms
    // Delay for 500ms to wait until end of selection anim.
    postDelayed(new ScreenTransitionOffHandler(currentMenu), 500); // Takes 1000ms
    // Delay for 1500ms to wait until end of transition off.
    postDelayed(new ScreenTransitionOnHandler(nextMenu), 1500);
}
```

You might chain the events by creating Actions (which fulfil the 'subject' role in the Observer pattern) and ActionObservers (which fulfil the 'observer' role):

```
void onItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Set up the actions
    // Actions call onCompleted() on any observers when they complete.
    SelectedItemAnimationAction sa = new SelectedItemAnimationAction(menuItem);
    ScreenTransitionOffAction stoff = new ScreenTransitionOffAction(currentMenu);
    ScreenTransitionOnAction ston = new ScreenTransitionOnAction(nextMenu);

    // Add some observers to the actions
    sah.addOnCompletedHandler(new ActionObserver() {
            public void onCompleted() {
                stoff.start();
            }
        });
    stoff.addOnCompletedHandler(new ActionObserver() {
            public void onCompleted() {
                ston.start();
            }
        });

    // Start the first action
    sa.start();
}
```

This way, you don't need to specify the duration of the SelectedItemAnimationHandler when you set up the ScreenTransitionOffHandler.

EDIT: Tried to make implementation of the Observer pattern clearer.
EDIT 2: Changed runNow(action) to action.start()

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it sounds like it could be a much better approach already. However, are you suggesting that I still use the Android Handler class? The method you suggest would still require manually setting timing values for each effect before running code via Handler.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense! Much appreciated, this is a big help :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit misleading. I've updated my answer and changed the confusing naming. I also tried to make the implementation of the observer pattern a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi again, I've just got one problem with this. I've implemented a small abstract class called Action which has an ArrayList of observers, and calls the observers onCompleted() methods in it's own onCompleted() method. However, I still have the problem of needing to call onCompleted() after all the effects are finished. At present, there are no delays and so everything would be run at once. Thanks again

Comment: Did another minor update for more clarity... So, at the moment you're calling `onCompleted()` for all the observers of an action from the action's `start()` method. Can you see the problem there?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I explained my last post badly. To make it clearer, if I called playAnimation(); onComplete(); which in turn calls start() on the observers, start() is still being called while the animation is still in progress. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: Each Action is going to need to know how long it lasts, and call `onComplete()` on its observers when it finishes. There's no way around that, but making it the responsibility of the Action makes things much more manageable and makes it easier to track down problems. There are various ways for actions to manage their timing - if they have an `update()` method then that would be the obvious place (just keep track of the time since the action started), otherwise you could use `Handlers` as you were before, though suggest `Timers` and `TimerTasks` might be a better fit.